# Trying to stop a block of characters from moving into another block of characters

Tags: c++, arrays, game-engine

```
    if(isEventMoveRight() == true)
    {
    if((playerX != 70) && (playerX+11 != 'T'))
    {
        playerX = playerX+1;
    }
}
```

'T' being the different block of characters from the player. Granted I'm not using an array for the block of 'T's or the background I'm only using one for the player, I think. I'm not sure if it's even using the array I set for the player correctly. In fact... I've got no idea how to use an array for a gameMap full stop.

I'll give you a run down of what I've got to do. Inside a console I have to use chars to create a game. I plan on having something pokemon-like with a guy being able to run round a screen and move the window when he reaches the edge of it like Zelda. Obviously I'm not making the entire game I'm just make one tiny part of it but that is all proving too much for me. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 but I have to use some guy's code that he's done to help us but to be honest it seems more of a hindrance than help because all the tutorials online about this are for just using C++ in VS2010 from scratch not from his code.

I first thought I could create an array called gameMap and populate it full of background spaces using two for loops. Then on top of that have an array for player, an array for obstacles and arrays for enemies using the same tactic. But for some bizarre reason I have to set the type of char the two for loops will print to the array[i][j] *inside* the two for loops even though beforehand in the code I have explicitly set what's in the array.
Example,

```
 char array[2][2] = {
 { '*', '*',},
 { '*', '*',},
 };
```

But as I said when I'm trying to just print out the array it's like it completely ignores what I've set to be in the array already and just prints out a bunch of 'asterisks'. It's fine for the background but when I want to print the player instead of printing a bunch of asterisks in a square it prints them in a long line and then the only way to make it so it appears right is to when printing out the player array, I have another for loop below which prints out the rest of the console window's worth of X, so in this case, 70 characters of blank spaces but that is of course completely wrong and not even a proper solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not completely clear on your question, I have some thoughts...

```
if(isEventMoveRight() == true)
{
    if((playerX != 70) && (playerX+11 != 'T'))
    {
        playerX = playerX+1;
    }
}
```

Do you mean `playerX+1`? Either way though, it appears you are not comparing to an array, but the value inside the array that represents a space you can't go. It seems like it should be something like this:

```
if(isEventMoveRight() == true)
{
    if((playerX < maximumX) && worldGrid(playerX+1, playerY).isWalkable)
    {
        playerX = playerX+1;
    }
}
```

where worldGrid() is a function that returns a reference to a struct that tells us the attributes of the given grid space.

As for your printing/debugging issue, note that many `char` values do not print letters or numbers. For example you might print a backspace character or tab character which changes the cursor position and may or may not overwrite stuff you wanted to see. So simply printing chars might not be the best way to debug `char` values, you might want to print the `char` value as `int`. Unless you are specifically using alphabet characters or other printable characters only.

You can convert char to an unsigned short like this:

```
(unsigned short)(0x00FF & charVariable);
```

Other thoughts based on what I understand from the question...
It sounds like you want one 2D array to essentially be the map where certain characters in the array represent different game assets such as a brick (can't walk through it) and a floor (can walk through it). These are probably stored as `char` so you get a maximum of 256 different types of panels/walls/stairs/etc. These are the things that do not move in the scene, only determine what the floor looks like underneath all the assets/items/characters.

(You might use a std::map along with a struct or a single 16bit int or some other int type that could be used as flags. Basically you want to be able to quickly look-up the attributes of each block of space in the world, such as whether or not you can walk through it or is it slippery, is it water, etc.)

Then you would probably want a second array to represent item placement and type. These might be treasure chests, destructible doors/caves, or movable bricks. These are items that the player can interact with, pick up, and/or use in puzzle solving.

I don't think you'd want the characters (both hero and villain) to be in a 2D array. In particular you don't want to traverse a huge array just to figure out where the character is. You probably also don't want any characters locked to grid spaces, unless you are making a text adventure, you would likely want them to be able to be in-between blocks on the map (like Zelda). With the hero you probably just have variables that say what the position and orientation are and other character attributes such as gold and health. No need for a 2D array.

With enemies, it would probably be good to use a `std::vector` or similar container because the number of them will change if one dies or spawns. And because you can iterate through a vector similar to how you might an array you can update all your enemies each time-step relatively easily and set a flag on them if they get killed so you can remove them from the vector after the update loop.

If you want to be able to have more than 1 hero, such as in local multi-player, you could always use a `std::vector` for heroes as well.